# C# create list of class with panel but it just disappear

Tags: c#

I've tried to create a list & class like this:

```
List<dialogbox> message = new List<dialogbox>();

public class dialogbox : Form1
        {
            private FlowLayoutPanel p = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            public dialogbox()
            {
                p.Name = "panel" + splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Count;
                splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(p);
                Console.WriteLine("splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Count = " + splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Count);
            }
        }
```

but when I test the program

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("message.Count = " + message.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Count = " + splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Count);

            message.Add(new dialogbox());

            Console.WriteLine("message.Count = " + message.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Count = " + splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Count);
        }
```

the console before  message.Add() :

> message.Count = 0
> splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Count = 0

because I count objects in splitContainer1.Panel1 again in the class dialogbox's constructor,it shows that the panel is **actually created!**

> splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Count = 1

but after this the panel just disappear but it seems like it still exist in List message, what is going on and how do I fix this?

> message.Count = 1
> splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Count = 0